# I have a list of structures in Swift and I want to check if any of that structures contains a specific String - how?

Tags: ios, swift

In my swift ios app I have a structure:

```
class SingleStructure: NSObject {

    let id: String
    let body: String
    var sent_at: NSDate
    var requiredId: String

}
```

I declared a list of those structures:

```
var singleStructuresList: [SingleStructure] = []
```

I also have a String file:

```
var someString: String = "hello"
```

and I want to check if `singleStructuresList` contains a `SingleStructure` that has a `requiredId` equal to my `someString`. How can I do it?

Comment: What did you try and what is the problem you faced?

Comment: First I operated on only `string` values - so a simple `.contains` method was enough, now I had to switch to the structures and I ok, I could do a `for` loop and look for it manually, but I suspect there might be a more practical solution. Since I don't have a big experience with Swift I've decided to ask here

Comment: Do you have lots of SingleStructures in your table? A for loop can be good solution: simple and easy to understand!

Comment: yes I do, actually it depends, mostly quite a few. I tried the solution proposed by Martin R for using extensions and I pasted `extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    func contains(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool
}` but I'm getting error on the `func...` line saying that `Expected { in body of function declaration`

Comment: You can try this one (tested in playground: search for a "T" 
 `let myarray = ["noop", "Test", "anoTher"]
var result =  myarray.map{ $0.containsString("T") }`
but you still have to iterrate result to search for true

Comment: Thanks! So what exactly do you mean by iterating result? Will that `myarray.map` return some kind of list of boolean values?

Comment: Yes, you can try it in a Playground: result is an array of boolean (.map always return an array)